# how to combine different partial orders (Poset)

Tags: order-theory

Given two posets $\prec_A$ and $\prec_B$ where $A\neq B$ and $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$, is there any way to combine them while preserving the exact information they exhibit - namely dominance relation ( $x\prec y$) and incomparability.
 (i.e. if $x$ and $y$ are incomparable in $\prec_A$ then they are incomparable in $\prec_{AB}$)?

Comment: What do you want to happen if $x \prec_A y$ and $y \prec_B x$?

Comment: @seteropere What is dominance?

Comment: @AndrewSalmon that's not going to happen since $\prec_A$ and $\prec_B$ are defined over different domains.. I have edited the question

Answer (score 4):

If $A\cap B=\varnothing$ you can define an order $<$ on $A\cup B$ by $x<y$ if, and only if:

1. $x,y\in A$ and $x\prec_A y$.
2. $x,y\in B$ and $x\prec_B y$.

This will preserve comparability. A diagram for this order can be obtained by placing the diagram for $A$ on the same plane as $B$.

---

Again assuming $A\cap B=\varnothing$, you can define an order $\ll$ on $A\cup B$ by $x\ll y$ if, and only if:

1. $x,y\in A$ and $x\prec_A y$
2. $x,y\in B$ and $x\prec_B y$.
3. $x\in A$ and $y\in B$

This will also preserve comparability. A diagram for this order can be obtained by placing the diagram for $A$ below the diagram for $B$ and connecting $A$'s maximal elements to $B$'s minimal elements if they exist.

Comment: Thanks.. but what about if $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $A\neq B$

Comment: @seteropere Depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$, you can make it such a way that $A\cap B'=\varnothing$, where $B'$ is something close enough to $B$. For instance you can take $B'=B\times \{x\}$, where $x$ is such that for all $b\in B$ you have $(b,x)\not \in A$.

Comment: @seteropere The above comment assumes you're looking for some pratical solution and not a theoretical one.

Comment: @seteropere: More generally, as long as $A\ne B$, you can simply replace $A$ by $A\times\{A\}$ and $B$ by $B\times\{B\}$; these new sets are disjoint, and partial orders isomorphic to $\prec_A$ and $\prec_B$ are easily defined on them.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I knew there was a better trick than what I suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. would you suggest a resource to read on combining/working on posets

Comment: @seteropere I wouldn't know about *combining*, as for order theory (that is posets and such), I like [Introduction to Lattices and Order](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Lattices-Order-B-Davey/dp/0521784514). It has a few chapters dedicated to computer science. There probably are other books with more applications to computers than this one.

Answer (score 1):

### Example where the combination of 2 Posets is not a Poset:

- <A={{1},{2,3},{4,5}}=SA and <B={{2,3},{5,6},{7}}=SB
- <(SA||SB)={{1},{2,3},{2,3},{4,5},{5,6},{7}} is not equal to <(∪)

### where :

- ∪ ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
- SA||SB being the concatenation of SA with SB
- SA||SB={{1},{2,3},{4,5},{2,3},{5,6},{7}}
- <(SA||SB) being the sorted concatenation of SA and SB

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).