# Union of two partial orderings

Tags: relations, order-theory

Suppose S and R are partial orderings. Does is necessarily mean that $R \cup S$ (union) is a partial ordering? If not what conditions would have to be met for it to be a partial ordering?

Comment: A sufficient (but perhaps not necessary) condition is that the domains of $S$ and $R$ be disjoint.

Comment: take the set to be $\{a,b\}$ with $S = \{(a,a), (a,b), (b,b)\}$ and $R = \{(a,a),(b,a),(b,b)\}$. Then the union fails to be antisymmetric.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352407/how-to-combine-different-partial-orders-poset).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [exitingcorpse remarks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416347/union-of-two-partial-orderings#comment890247_416347), antisymmetry may fail.

Transitivity can be a problem too, for example on domain $\{a,b,c\}$, with $S=\{(a,a), (b,b), (a,b),(c,c)\}, R= \{(a,a),(b,c),(c,c),(b,b)\}$. Then the union $S \cup R$ is not transitive: $(a,c)$ should be in it as $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are...

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematics.SE and thank you for your answer! I've enhanced the typesetting of your answer. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).